# Proper way to return different values from one function

Tags: c++, visual-c++, return

Newbie question.
Please see the code below:

```
FB::variant TestPluginAPI::getmidX()
{
RECT rect; 
HWND hWnd;
hWnd = getBrowserHwnd();
if(GetWindowRect(hWnd, &rect))
    {

  int width = rect.right - rect.left;
  int height = rect.bottom - rect.top;
  int left = rect.left;
  int mid = (rect.right + rect.left)/2;
  return mid;
    }
else {return 0;}
}
```

What I want - is to be able to get from this function `mid` and, for example `left`, to use it in different variables in my another function. I can of course just copy it and make function that returns only `left`... is it a proper way to do such things, or there is more elegant one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want something like this:

```
return std::make_pair(mid,left)
```

and the return type of you function would need to be `std::pair<int, int>`. Then when you call you need to do so like this: `std::pair<int,int> value = getmidX();` and if you need the mid, you would do `int mid = value.first` and if you need the left, you would do `int left = value.second;`

To use this you need a relatively modern C++ compiler (pretty sure a recent VC++ would work) and you need to `#include<utility>`

Answer (score 3):

There are several options. The `struct` solutions have been given, but (in my opinion) they are not the best way.

You should know that you can modify the parameters to a function, so you can do this:

```
int getMidX( int &left, int &width ) {
    // do stuff
    left = theLeftNumber;
    width = theWidthNumber;
    return theMidNumber;
}
```

and call it with this:

```
int l;
int w;
int m = getMidX( l, w );
```

You can also use pointers instead of references, which lets you make the return values optional and works in C too (use `*` instead of `&`, and change the call to `getMidX( &l, &r )`. You should also check for NULL inside the function to know which values the user is interested in).

Comment: Yes, know about it, but i think it's not my case, cos i need to return few values, that just differently calculated from the same given to function values. But thx anyway)

Comment: @SinnerSmile I don't think you understand; the function isn't *reading* the values of `l` and `w`, it's *setting* them. Hence giving you 3 "returned" values.

Answer (score 2):

If you would like to return more stuff, you can define struct and return struct from the function.
For example:

```
struct funcRetrun
{
  int left;
  int mid;
  int right;
}
```

you can then return those stuff inside the function, however, this is not very elegant since you need to change your function return type to funcReturn.

Since C++11, you can use `std::tuple` if you would like to return more:

`Tuples are objects that pack elements of -possibly- different types together in a single object, just like pair objects do for pairs of elements, but generalized for any number of elements.`